# Why are there blanks when selecting multiple lines in a text file?

Tags: text-editors, text-editing, ide

When selecting mutiple lines on an IDE / Notepad on Windows, there are blank characters at the end of each line.

[image: blank characters demonstration]

You can't move the cursor through them when using the arrow keys, they only appear when selecting text. Why? What are they? Are they newline characters?

Comment: If you copy and paste the text, are they included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visible space at the end of the line when selecting text is simply representative of the line break character that is there.

> You can't move the cursor through them when using the arrow keys, they only appear when selecting text.

You actually do move through "them" when moving with the cursor, when you jump to the next line. You can also select them directly by starting to select from after the last character and selecting until the first character of the next line:
[image]

If you select it and press delete, the two lines will become one.

In most IDEs/Text Editors, you can set to show all characters, in which case it will show the line-break (non-printable) character there:
[image]

Comment: I see, thanks ! I messed around a bit with the keyboard shortcuts, and saw that on notepad++ you can add `CR` and `LF` separately (with CTRL+Shift+M and CTRL+Shift+J respectively), though they seem to have the same effect. Why is that ?

Comment: A new question should really be asked as a new separate question... But if your question is why there is a CR & LF for a line break when you can have either of them separately. This is because of OS compatibility, Windows generally does the CR LF sequence while some other OSs might do only one of the two.